# How to sum a mathmatical result from two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, mysql-8.0

Not sure what to do!

Using MySQL

I need to display the total trips per hour a specific operatorID

So the total tripsperhour for operatorid '2' should be displayed as a number '7' somewhere. This number '7' is the sum of TripsPerHour.

```
SELECT S.routeid, S.operatorid, R.routeid, S.percentage * R.frequency/100 AS TripsPerHour 
  FROM route_split S, routes R 
 WHERE R.routeid = S.routeid
   AND S.operatorid ='2';
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
| routeid | operatorid | routeid | TripsPerHour |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
|       6 |          2 |       6 |       1.0000 |
|      12 |          2 |      12 |       4.0000 |
|      13 |          2 |      13 |       2.0000 |
+---------+------------+---------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It's best to clarify which SQL database you're working with, as syntax can differ between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `SUM()` aggregation along with `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT S.operatorid, R.routeid, 
       SUM(S.percentage * R.frequency/100) AS TripsPerHour 
  FROM route_split S
  JOIN routes R 
    ON R.routeid = S.routeid
 GROUP BY S.operatorid, R.routeid
```

If you only need the value with `operatorid=2`, then add

```
WHERE S.operatorid = 2
```

before `GROUP BY` such as

```
SELECT R.routeid, 
       SUM(S.percentage * R.frequency/100) AS TripsPerHour 
  FROM route_split S
  JOIN routes R 
    ON R.routeid = S.routeid
 WHERE S.operatorid = 2
 GROUP BY R.routeid
```

**Update :** you can add `SUM() OVER ()` window function provided that your DB version is `8.0+` such as

```
SELECT S.operatorid, R.routeid,
       SUM(S.percentage * R.frequency/100) OVER () AS Total_TripsPerHour 
  FROM route_split S
  JOIN routes R 
    ON R.routeid = S.routeid
 WHERE S.operatorid = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I need to have the sum of the TripsPerHour as a separate output.

Comment: you're welcome @rowan333 , can you elaborate explicitly what you mean by editing the question please?

Comment: well, what's the version of MySQL DB @rowan333 ?

Comment: 8.0.22 is the version

Comment: nice, then you can use the window function as I mentioned within the answer @rowan333

Comment: I am getting this error: ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bus_network.S.percentage' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: well, we need to remove GROUP BY in this case @rowan333

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks for your help. Thats exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the WITH ROLLUP option to get your cumulative sum as a separate row:

```
         SELECT  S.operatorid, R.routeid, 
       SUM(S.percentage * R.frequency/100) AS TripsPerHour ) FROM
  route_split S JOIN routes R 
    ON R.routeid = S.routeid GROUP BY S.operatorid, R.routeid WITH ROLLUP
```

Whichever answer you choose, do an EXPLAIN on it before you put it into production.